# How to enable native events with Selenium Webdriver integrated with Maven and Jenkins (Java & IE)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to know how to enable the native events for Jenkins, when I run the tests locally with maven everything works fine. When running the test via Jenkins it seems like Jenkins does not recognize the key events being inputed. However this issue could be because Jenkins does not open a browser window on the server. It only runs the test via a virtual browser.

```
runner.getDriverWrapper().findElement(By.id("search__unit__personalization")).click();
runner.getDriverWrapper().skrivInText("Selmas");

public void skrivInText(String textToSelect){
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.sendKeys(new String[] {textToSelect});
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    actions.build().perform();

runner.getDriverWrapper().findElement(By.id("personalization__done")).click();
```

Comment: How you have implemented the native events functionality ? Is it in Java or AutoIT(for windows) ? Code snippet will be very helpful.

Comment: Native events related to browser. So, you should also provide us the driver information.

Comment: @ShoaibMal updated the description

Comment: @Saifur updated the description

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to enable the native events in the Firefox browser ­

1. Create an object reference for FirefoxProfile predefined class of Selenium.
   here no need to represent any specific Firefox Profile
2. setEnableNativeEvents() is a predefined method of FirefoxProfile class
   Pass boolean value 'true' to enable the native events in our automation code
   Run the code having advanced user interactions like Actions Class > moveToElement()
   etc.
   If synthetic events are not working, enabling the native events this way will allow the browser to generate JavaScript events and make our automation code work properly.

   ```
   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

   profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);

   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
   ```

Comment: "setEnableNativeEvent" does not seem to be there in selelium 4 / Windows